# How to reduce database hits in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a scenario and i want to know bestpractices to reduce database hits. Scenario is I have a dictionary table in my application where i put all the words/keywords for translation purpose because my system is multilingual.
Keywords are placed all over the page they can be 10 to 20 in one page and on each word it fetches the translation from database if user in not viewing english version of website.

My application in on Asp.Net MVC 2 with C# and LINQ2SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caching is a good way to reduce database queries. There are 2 levels of cache you could use:

- Cache objects (for example results of database queries)
- Cache HTML output of entire controller actions or partials

Comment: caching is a good way to reduce db queries but i want to reduce hits for each word. If i have 20words on one page i want to get all in one hit rather than 20 hits

Answer (score 8):

The translation typically don't change very often and the amount of data is limited. Read up *all* translated strings when the web app is started and put them in a globally accessible Dictionary. Whenever you need the translated strings, look them up in the dictionary.

Comment: +1 - almost to a 't' exactly what i'd suggest based on the available info

Answer (score 2):

linq will lazy load, which means the queries won't hit the database unless you access a property returned by the query, so make sure you avoid accessing property before they are really needed.

you could also try to combine linq queries into one and have a look at your loops to make sure there isn't a better way to cycle through your queries.

you should also be able to remove database access altogether and use translation files in xml rather than on a database.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can do things like caching and lazy loading, etc... it's best to figure out WHAT is going wrong.

Enter [LinqToSql Profiler](http://l2sprof.com/). Yes, it's a commercial product .. but it's worth it. Also, it has a DEMO period ..

This can show you the crap performing queries .. and which queries are doing N+1, etc....

[image]

Comment: The Sql server profiler or [if you use express] Anjlab sql profiler does the same and is free. Only you need to do it while debugging